# window startup can't access boot files like winload.exe

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I am having a single 450GB drive on my laptop PC. I tried to shrink it using third party app "Minitool partition wizard" as the default disk management tool was saying "Not enough space available to shrink" even after the space was available. 
  I restarted the PC as it asked to do so. The partitioning was going on Black screen(DOS like) and suddenly it stopped, attempted to restart but error occured as the system wasn't able to access boot files.(can't access winload.exe, error 0xc000000f)

After this i booted into Ubuntu via live USB and even it is not able to access that ntfs partition(showing error sign in gparted too).

After this I tried to access file explorer from advanced startup(using command prompt, taskmanager) but nothing happening at all.

I had created restore point before doing all this but it is not found by system now.

I even tried to reset my PC but there is a problem there too(error was not mentioned).

So I googled it and I can say what 'partition tool wizard' did to my PC is, it was trying to move some data from one location to another and in all this it moved the system files too and now nothing can be accessed on all of that drive. I had all of my data on that C:/ drive and i want to recover my data atleast.

System configurations:

HP 15-d103tx notebook PC.

OS: Window 10 pro (latest build)

Comment: if you had a livecd, why didn't you try to shrink with gparted?

Comment: Yeah, I should have done that. But I was not expecting all this, next time I'll do it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to remove the hard drive and move it to another functioning computer to recover the data at a byte level.  The data itself will be fine even if the partition table is corrupted (assuming you weren't using full hard drive encryption).

Once you've backed up your data, then do a low-level format on the drive and a fresh install of your desired OS.

The alternative is byte-level modification of the partition table, which is ugly, has a low success rate, and may screw up your data further.  Best to not attempt it and get your data off the drive while it's still there.

UPDATE:

If the file system is completely corrupt and standard file recovery programs like `Testdisk` don't work, the best bet is to use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to access the files directly at a byte level, ignoring the corrupt partitions/file systems.

Comment: thank for the advice but I'm having a doubt whether the hard drive would be able to read even on another PC or not as I guess the main problem is that any OS is not able to access the drive.

Comment: Recovery software will be able to access the drive at a byte level even if the partition tables are corrupt.  As long as the drive is visible in the BIOS of the computer, recovery software can see it.  It won't show up as a lettered drive in Windows, but that's not required for recovery software to see it.  I've had good luck with Testdisk: [ http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk ] but there are lots of other options.

Comment: TestDisk is maybe the best tool in this situation. Eventually understanding about disk structure, partitions is needed. I think TestDisk can be installed to a Windows recovery USB (added to .wim using dism). TestDisk is a command line utility.

Comment: I tried to access the drive using ubuntu (via testdisk) but it says **file system is damaged**. one more thing is that other drive(system created) can be accessed simply using ubuntu so the whole disk is not damaged. As it is not being booted at all then how will it do anything on another system?

Comment: If even TestDisk can't see the files, try `PhotoRec`: [ http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec ].  It ignores the file system and searches for file signatures in the raw bytes.  That way it doesn't matter if the file system or partitions are damaged.

Comment: I created the image of that disk using `TestDisk` and successfully recovered desired files using `PhotoRec`. I didn't have to remove the harddisk  as I could did this all using liveUSB(Ubuntu).